# Android .cer import to sdcard fails

Tags: android, android-emulator, ssl-certificate, android-sdcard

I'm trying to import an SSL certificate(.cer file) to android emulator and I'm facing the below issue.

The sdcard folder is shown in 2 places of Data Explorer in eclipse. One is 'sdcard', another is inside 'mnt->sdcard'
When I try to push .cer file to sdcard folder it says 'Failed to push:null'. 
However When I try to push it to mnt->sdcard folder, it accepts and the file is imported.

Having done this, I tried to install the certificate through emulator. It says 'No certificates found' in sdcard folder.

What could be the cause?? Please provide your inputs.

Regards,
Sankar